# Flutter Widgets and MaterialApp()

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Do I need to surround each of my screens with MaterailApp() widget or can I render all screens in one place and wrap them all in one place??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in most cases there will be only 1 `MaterialApp` widget in your app. While you need to wrap each of your screens with a `Scaffold` widget.

Answer (score 1):

MaterialApp is a predefined class in a flutter. It is like the main or core component of flutter. We can access all the other components and widgets provided by Flutter SDK, like StatelessWidget, StatefulWidget, AppBar widget, Scaffold widget, IconButton widget, TextField widget, Padding widget, and many more.

MaterialApp() widget is a top-level widget in flutter better you write it once and then display other widgets within it.